# Pending transactions are not mined

Tags: go-ethereum, transactions, truffle, truffle-contract, pending-transactions

## Preconditions

I'm running a private network with Geth, having custom smart contracts deployed by Truffle and a simple frontend which using Metamask as a provider to connect the network.

### Versions

- Geth: 1.8.12-stable
- Truffle: v4.1.13 (core: 4.1.13)
- Solidity: v0.4.24 (solc-js)

### Genesis Block

```
{
    "config": {
        "chainId": 331788,
        "homesteadBlock": 0,
        "eip155Block": 331788,
        "eip158Block": 0
    },
    "nonce": "0x0000000000000000",
    "timestamp": "0x00",
    "parentHash": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
    "extraData": "0x00",
    "gasLimit": "10000100000",
    "difficulty": "20",
    "mixhash": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
    "coinbase": "0x0d33f764b19d03df4daa283859577378a01c5cad",
    "alloc": {
        "0x0d33f764b19d03df4daa283859577378a01c5cad": { "balance": "1000000" }
    }
}
```

### Initing the private network

```
geth --identity "node" --rpc --rpcport "8545" --rpccorsdomain "*" --datadir=/ethereum/data --ethash.dagdir=/ethereum/ethash --port "30303" --nodiscover --rpcapi "db,eth,net,admin,web3,debug" --networkid 331788 init /ethereum/genesis.json
geth --identity "node" --rpc --rpcaddr="0.0.0.0" --rpcport "8545" --rpccorsdomain "*" --datadir=/ethereum/data --ethash.dagdir=/ethereum/ethash --port "30303" --nodiscover --verbosity=9 --rpcapi "admin,db,eth,net,web3,miner,personal,debug" --networkid 331788
```

## Preparation

Once the private network is up, I connect to it via `geth attach` and then run the following:

```
personal.unlockAccount(web3.eth.coinbase, "123123", 150000);
miner.setGasPrice(1); miner.setEtherbase(personal.listAccounts[0]); miner.start(5);
```

So I unlock my coinbase account and start 5 miners with gas price value 1. After some time, I'm able to deploy my contracts which I do next. So they take the first three nonce values for my coinbase account. When contract is deploying `txpool.inspect` shows me the following:

```
pending: {
  0x0D33f764b19d03DF4DAa283859577378a01C5Cad: {
    2: "contract creation: 0 wei + 10010000 gas × 32 wei"
  }
},
queued: {}
```

Contracts are deployed okay.

## Sending transactions

On the frontend, I have the following code to send transaction to my custom contract using `truffle-contract` abstraction:

```
sampleNameContract().use(function (instance) {
        return instance.addRecord(recordId, address, recordId, address, { gas: "0x10000", from: address })
    }).then(function (value) {
        console.log(`Tx: ${value}`)
    })
```

Executing this snippet, Metamask asks me to approve transaction and I do it. As a result, I have the following info in `txpool.inspect`:

```
pending: {
      0x0D33f764b19d03DF4DAa283859577378a01C5Cad: {
        3: "0x440C9c5DBC21cedcAfF1a98ac7A48b5c6930cd0c: 0 wei + 10010000 gas × 32000000000 wei"
      }
    },
    queued: {}
```

This transaction is never mined and applied and leaves in the tx pool as a pending one forever.

## Issue

The transaction I send to my custom contract from the frontend is never mined and applied. Can you please help me figure this out?

Comment: Not directly related. But this might give you some ideas/pointers: https://medium.com/@jgm.orinoco/releasing-stuck-ethereum-transactions-1390149f297d

Answer (score 0):

Try to execute a transaction using address `0x0d33f764b19d03df4daa283859577378a01c5cad` for which you had already preallocated some ethers. It might be possible that transaction cost is comparatively high and need more time to mine sufficient ethers to execute a transaction.

Comment: Hi asvisosila, Currently, my account has 55130.000 ETH. How can I get my current transaction cost on that private network?

Comment: Are you able to deploy your contract on ganache? I recommend you to use ganache for development and testing of DAPP. Ganache pre-allocates 100 ethers in 10 accounts(default is 10) initially so that you can quickly test your application.

Comment: asvisosila, No, I'm running geth node where I'm able to deploy contracts without errors using Truffle. However, I have to try using something else to get it worked since I could not mange to fix that so far :(